# MySQL insert ignore in PHP with where statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL statement in a PHP file that imports a .csv file.  The statement successfully ignores exact record matches but I am getting some duplicate records in the table where the records are not exact 100%.  I did notice that in those cases where duplicates are occuring the LATITUDE and LONGITUDE is still always the same.  Is there a way to expand this with some sort of WHERE statement to also exclude records on import if these two fields already have a match in the table?  I've tried all sorts of WHERE attempts and get a MySQL error?

```
    $query = "insert ignore into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a unique index on multiple columns in mysql directly.

In mysql it would be something like (for 2 columns from memory...):

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` ADD UNIQUE `some_name_like_position` ( `LATITUDE` , `LONGITUDE` );
```

Comment: So if I set a primary key on MLS_LISTING_ID, LATITUDE and LONGITUDE for example must all 3 match for a record to be omitted?  Is it possible to omit if MLS_LISTING_ID OR (LATITUDE and LONGITUDE) matches?

Comment: @Rocco The Taco Yes, the combination of the 3 is defined as unique so you cannot add a new row with the exact same 3 values but 2 the same ones and 1 different one will enter.

Comment: Excellent.  That was my problem, I did not account that the MLS could be different.  I set MLS as the primary and then created an index for Lat/Long and it worked.  Thanks so much for the help!